# three.js: how to transition smoothly between 3 animation sequence states in the animate loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm trying to get the transitions of the 3 different wing flapping sequences to happen smoothly over a short time. Right now they just jump from one state to another.  There are 3 states for the wings flapping, 1) On the ground. 2) Flying up. 3) Flying down. It's confusing because anything in the loop gets looped, but this would be a smooth one time transition each time the state changes. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rCsmTDf6tQ8ZcbkGjkqh?p=preview)

Here's the relevant JS:

```
Pig.prototype.updateWingsFly = function() {
    this.wingAngle += this.wingSpeed/globalSpeedRate;
    this.wingL.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4 + Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude;
    this.wingR.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4 - Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude;
}

Pig.prototype.updateWingsDescend = function() {
    this.wingAngle += this.wingSpeed/globalSpeedRate;
    this.wingL.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 2 + Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude / 4;
    this.wingR.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2 - Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude / 4 ;
}

Pig.prototype.updateWingsRest = function() {
    this.wingAngle += this.wingSpeed/globalSpeedRate;
    this.wingL.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 4 + Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude / 8;
    this.wingR.rotation.z = Math.PI / 4 - Math.cos(this.wingAngle) * this.wingAmplitude / 8;

}

function loop(){
    render();
    var xTarget = (mousePos.x-windowHalfX);
    var yTarget= (mousePos.y-windowHalfY);
    pig.look(xTarget, yTarget);
    getFlyPosition();


    if (objectHeight === 0){
          pig.updateWingsRest();
          } else if (isFlyingUp){
          pig.updateWingsFly();
          } else {
          pig.updateWingsDescend();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

Comment: One way to achieve this effect would be to use morphTargets, but I think you'd need to create the targets using a modelling tool, (and possibly the animation loops too)

Comment: @AgentZebra: have you been able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

Tween.js is your solution. It's used for changing values of variables in a smooth way, and it works great for smoothing 3DObjects animations.

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I don't think this is the solution by itself, can you explain how these states might be smoothly animated between? Being that they're triggered from a loop, any tween.js or GSAP code is just looped rather than played once the transition of course just needs to animate once each time, and these are dynamic states, what variables to tween? Can you be more specific? Thanks!